# Android crashes when calling ImageButton

Tags: android, imagebutton

I have a crash (Application Stopped Unexpectedly) problem with this main.xml is a "HelloWorld" type project (while testing and learning features I need for my app) :

I isolated the ImageButton as an issue, but I can't isolate any of the parameters...

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageButton android:id="@+id/picture"    
    android:layout_width="240dip"    
    android:layout_height="180dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:src="@drawable/icon"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"     
    android:cropToPadding="true"    
    android:clickable="true"    
    android:scaleType="fitCenter" />    

</LinearLayout>
```

icon.png exists in my resources...
I can see the preview in the Layout tab, even though the image is not centered on the button, but I read that it was normal.

The code below works fine (as a regular Button). I can also do the same as an ImageView.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
     android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <Button android:id="@+id/picture"
    android:layout_width="240dip"
    android:layout_height="180dip"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I use Eclipse and the AVD, and all my learning is done on 2.1 (SDK level 7).
I can't test the app on an actual device yet as I don't have it yet.

Thanks in advance !

Comment: You need to post the Java stacktrace from the LogCat view in Eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh bother !!
It seems that it was a java error in my MyApp.java, when I was trying to declare the event for the button. Case closed. Sorry.